# Laravel with Inertia working fine on local on hard reload on every routes but not work on production server properly

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, inertiajs

Hi Guys I am work on laravel and Inertia

My code working fine on every route on local machine, when i hard reload on production server it give me 500 server error, if i dont hard reload my website it works fine what is issue. please tell me
work if i do not hard reload it. return 500 error if i make it hard reload.

```
>
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Inertia\Inertia;
use App\Repository\ProjectRepository;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;




class ProjectController extends Controller
{
    private $projectRepository;

    public function __construct(ProjectRepository $projectRepository){
        $this->projectRepository = $projectRepository;
    }

    public function index() {
        $response = $this->projectRepository->getList();
        return Inertia::render('Admin/Project/View',[
            'list' => $response['list'],
            'manager' => $response['manager'],
            'labor' => $response['labor'],
            'materials' => $response['materials'],
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share more details, like the raw error message. Usually, when facing an error 500, there are more details, either in your server's error log or in the application's log